# AWS EC2 deploy Mean stack project

Tags: amazon-ec2, mean-stack

I tried deploying My application I have angular express/Node and Mongo,
I tried to do nginx for Angular, set sites-available nginix config to the index.html of angular after the ng build prod from my local and transferred  files to server,
Also i did npm start for Node and also started Mongo,
Now the node shows as started and node listens on port 3001 for me but i see that the Angular isnt able to communicate with backend and I see 404 in console logs of angular.
Also i am not sure about the structure of Mean projects for deployment,
 should they be in one project only as in the ng build --prod files should be inside node directories and should be refereed or something

Comment: I also did not get a compelling video tutorial on youtube hence posting it here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I resolved this issue in the following way:

1. added a /api in the nodes link(path formed on the server) which is formed when hitting the backend from angular.
2. wrote a bypass in nginx sites-available/*file-name* for the /api to be redirected to port 301 which corresponds to node.
3. for the non /api keep it on the localhost's same port that is 80 in my case or may change if you have configured https.

If you have a better and a standard approach please do answer this seems a workaround for me